# How to fix lags on webkit/iphone when using transform rotate in radial progress bar

Tags: css, webkit

I am using this radial progress bar: http://jsfiddle.net/andsens/mLA7X/
It uses transform: rotate(); to visually display a percentage (e.g. 80%).

It works like a charm in chrome and FF, however it seems to 'lag' in webkit (e.g. my iPhone, see pictures below). I've tried to following to fix the lag:

`.mask, .fill {-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;}`

however, it doesn't seem to work. This was the only advice I could find on this issue, that's why I am now asking SO. I hope you guys can help.

[image: Initial state] Initial state

[image: showing lag during transition to final state] Showing lag during transition to final state

[image: Final stage] Final stage. No problems.

Feel free to check-out the lag yourself. (It appears when loading bigger percentages (>60%).)

Comment: Do you have the same issue in the demo jsfiddle ?

Comment: yes. both on the live site and in the jsfiddle on iOS 9.0.2 whenever a bigger percentage (say >70%) is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS `clip` property is [deprecated](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/). You can use `clip-path` instead.

I tested to find that `clip-path` works flawlessly on desktop Safari and every web browser on iPhone (Safari, Chrome and embedded browser) but behaves weirdly on desktop Chrome. That's why we are going to use `clip-path` on iPhone and desktop Safari but use `clip` on others.

First, check the browser with javascript:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isIphone = ua.indexOf('iphone') != -1;
var isSafari = ua.indexOf('safari') != -1 && ua.indexOf('chrome') == -1;
if (isIphone || isSafari) {
    $('body').addClass('safari');
}
```

And change your CSS codes on line 38:

```
.mask {
    clip: rect(0px, @circle-size, @circle-size, @circle-size/2);
    .fill {
        clip: rect(0px, @circle-size/2, @circle-size, 0px);
        background-color: @circle-color;
    }
}
```

to this:

```
.mask {
    clip: rect(0px, @circle-size, @circle-size, @circle-size/2);
    .fill {
        clip: rect(0px, @circle-size/2, @circle-size, 0px);
        background-color: @circle-color;
    }

    body.safari & {
        clip: auto;
        -webkit-clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px @circle-size/2);
        .fill {
            clip: auto;
            -webkit-clip-path: inset(0px @circle-size/2 0px 0px);
        }
    }
}
```

You can test by yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/64dtpsba/4/